# Detecting NPAPI support using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, npapi, browser-plugin

How can you detect if a browser supports NPAPI from JavaScript? Not all of them do, and whilst I could rely on the user-agent I'd much rather do it a more reliable way if one exists.

Unfortunately, I can't simply detect if my plug-in has loaded or not, as it may be that the plugin simply isn't installed yet on a supported browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no JS API for this, but basically all desktop browsers except IE-/Trident-based ones and ChromeOS support NPAPI.

You can find out wether your plugin is installed by checking [`navigator.plugins`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.plugins).

Comment: "Non-desktop" is a pretty big exception at this point though. Also, ChromeOS doesn't support NPAPI, and there are non-IE Trident-based browsers like Avant and Maxthon. So it's not exactly trivial to get a UA list right.

Comment: Ok, ChromeOS complicates things. While there are other questions on mobile/IE/... detection, some UA check on *"Trident"*, IE, *"Mobi"* and *"CrOS"* should probably work at the moment?

Comment: It's shame there's no API. Luckily, my NPAPI plugin is 32bit Windows only, so I can reasonably reliably check for a UA that contains "Windows NT" and not ("Win64" or "Trident").

Comment: Note that this has been further complicated by Chrome deprecating NPAPI: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28766423/230167

Answer (score -2):

If you want to check whether java plugins are enabled or not in the browser then you should use the `navigator.javaEnabled()`. It will work in chrome.